# how does following program work  in printf

Tags: c

Here is a program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i=2;
printf("I=%d i=%d\n",++i,++i);
}
```

The output I got was

```
4 4
```

it is a bit surprising output to me.
How does that ++i works? and why is that giving `4 4` and not `3 4` in result?

Just read it ,it is different from the thread which you people are  marking it as duplicate.

Comment: Questions like this have been asked *a lot* on this site. You should make a point to search for existing questions before you ask a new one.

Comment: shame on people who closed it without even understanding what the problem was.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, for what it's worth. Anyway, the point is that answers to this question are essentially the same as those to existing questions: namely, that reading and writing a variable without an intervening sequence point is undefined behaviour, and the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants.

Comment: The issue is exactly the same, even if the program is slightly different. You're modifying (and reading) `i` twice in the same instruction (precisely speaking, you're modifying `i` twice with no intervening sequence point). See also [C programming: is this undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450582) with a similar example where `i` is written once and read twice.

Answer (score 2):

Undefined behavior. You shouldn't change value of the variable and read it multiple times in the same [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).