# why the results differ based on the compiler(gcc and turboC)

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this undefined C behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450582/is-this-undefined-c-behaviour)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=5;
    printf("%d %d %d",a++,a++,++a);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

**In gcc:**

```
7 6 8
```

**In TURBO C:**

```
7 6 6
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the order of evaluation of arguments to a function is **unspecified** and may vary from compiler to compiler. An compile may evaluate function arguments from:
left to right or
right to left or
in any other pattern.

This order is not specified by the C standard.

Reference:

**C99 Standard 6.5**

> "The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.72) Except as specified later (for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:, and comma operators), the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified."

Answer (score 3):

The order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified. Compilers are free to implement it in any way they choose. Code like this will be brittle and unreliable.